# A question about the statement of Lemma $1.1.3$ in Huybrechts' Complex Geometry

Tags: complex-analysis

On page $6$, Lemma $1.1.3$ of Huybrechts' *Complex Geometry*, it says

> Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ and let $V \subset \mathbb{C}$ be an open neighbourhood of the boundary of $B_{\epsilon}(0) \subset \mathbb{C}$ where $\mathbb{C}$ is the complex plane. Assume that $f: V\times U \to \mathbb{C}$ is a holomorphic function. Then $g(z)= \int f(\eta, z_1, \dots, z_n)\,d\eta$ is a holomorphic function on $U$.

What is the meaning of "let $V \subset \mathbb{C}$ be an open neighbourhood of the boundary of $B_{\epsilon}(0) \subset \mathbb{C}$"? Is $B_{\epsilon}(0) \subset \mathbb{C}$ the boundary of $V$ or $V$ is a open neighbourhood of $B_{\epsilon}(0) \subset \mathbb{C}$ or $V$ is an open neighbourhood containing $B_{\epsilon}(0) \subset \mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Let $V \subset \mathbb{C}$ be an open neighbourhood of the boundary of $B_{\varepsilon}(0) \subset \mathbb{C}$" means $V$ is an open set containing $\partial B_{\varepsilon}(0)$.

The statement in your post is incomplete; you have not indicated what you are integrating over in the definition of $g$. In the book, it defines $$g(z) := g(z_1, \dots, z_n) = \int_{|\xi|=\varepsilon}f(\xi, z_1, \dots, z_n)\, d\xi.$$ Now note that $\{\xi \in \mathbb{C} \mid |\xi| = \varepsilon\} = \partial B_{\varepsilon}(0)$; this is why you need $V$ to be an open neighbourhood of $\partial B_{\varepsilon}(0)$.

Comment: could I ask you a question regarding the proof of this LEmma

Comment: I haven't looked at the proof in a long time. I think it would be better to ask a separate question.